# navigating to another component in the same page layout

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a list of data which i am displaying using map on the left side of the screen , upon clicking the , a new component should be rendered in the right side of the same screen and also the url has to change in the browser , thought of using onClick instead of Link to but if used then cannot specify the change of url .

```
const Home = (props) => {
return(
<div className="main-wrapper">
  <div className="service-wrapper">
    <Service/>
  </div>
  <div className="list-wrapper">
    <Route path="/service/service_name" exact component={List}/>
  </div>
</div>
);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React router v4 makes use of dynamic routing ie your new component can render if the location matches the right route.

To achieve what you want, you can add a Route with the specific link path that will render the new component.

In your code just make the change in the following line:-

```
 <div className="list-wrapper">
       <Route path="Your path" component={List} /> 
 </div>
```

Comment: so your saying instead of defining my routes in app.js , i have to define here (the right side of my page render) ?

Comment: No, keep those routes as they are in the app.js. Just add another <Route> here.

Comment: yes tried it , but it still gets routed to the next page , My structure is as follows : first i have my app.js wherin there is a button which upon click goes to services , which has services listed and upon clicking any one of the services from the left side , it gets routed to the List component and should render it in the right side .

Comment: have updated , My Home.js consists of services and list , services being the left side , and inside the services i have used Link to so that when clicked it goes to the List component which according to the route should be rendered in the right side .

Answer (score 0):

You can use onClick but then you will have to use history object provided by the react router library.
It will look like this:-

```
onClick(() => history.push(`/service/${service}`));
```

To access history you will have to import withRouter hoc from react router library.

```
    import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";


    class YourComponent extends Component {

      const { history } = this.props;

    }

    export default withRouter(YourComponent);
```

Left and right dashboard structure should look this this:-

```
const LeftDashboard = () => {
   return (
    <div>
     // rest of your ui
    </div>
   )
}

const RightDashboard = ({ activeParam }) => {

  const renderActive = () => {
     switch(activeParam) {
    case 1:
     return somecomponent;
    case 2:
     return someother;
    default:
     return defaultcomponent;
   }  
  }

   return renderActive();
}

 class App extends Component {

  render() {
   <React.Fragment>
    <LeftDashboard />
    <RightDashboard activeParam={//pass active param} />
   </React.Fragment> 
  }
 }
```

Another option will be to put your routes in the right dashboard component:-

```
const RightDashboard = () => {
   return (
    <React.Fragment>
     <Route path="/somepath" component={<Mycomponent />} />
     <Route path="/someotherpath" component={<Myothercomponent />} />
    </React.Fragment>
   )

}
```

And rest of the structure will remain same as above.

Comment: It is still going to the next page instead of loading the contents on the right side ,  when i click any one of the elements in the left side

Comment: See you have to prepare a layout with a left side dashboard and a right dashboard. And you have to render that in the app root. Now, based on the current route you have to pass active param to the right dashboard which will render the new component with left dashboard still in place.

Comment: Check the updated answer. This is one of the several ways this can be achieved.

Comment: So instead of Link i have to use a normal <a> and use onClick with history.push in it ??

Comment: No. You can use either Link or onClick handler. That's upto you. <a> tag is not used for routing inside react. You can use onClick with history.push on a regular div